# Transition Animation on UITextView (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I'm wondering if I can create a transition animation for every time my TextView gets a new Text?, it gets its content text dynamically. I'm using Swift 2 (Xcode 7)

```
let textContent = "New Text shows here"
textView.text = textContent
```

I know UIView can help, but I am using UITextView, any way I can achieve this?

Please Help!

Comment: ever found a solution?